# XRremote throws System Exeption work

Tags: 8thwall-xr

8XRremote don't work.
Android app connect to windows via WIFI. And in unity console there is the following log:

```
C:/Users/Tim/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb threw exception System.Exception: "C:/Users/Tim/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb forward --list" exited with 1
  at XRInternal.XREditorBridge+XRRemoteUtils.ExecuteCommand (System.String command, System.String arguments) [0x000d3] in G:\temp\8xr\xr-unity-master\projects\8thWallXR-Demo\Assets\XR\Scripts\XREditorBridge.cs:334 
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
XRInternal.XRRemoteUtils:ExecuteCommand(String, String) (at Assets/XR/Scripts/XREditorBridge.cs:338)
XRInternal.XRRemoteUtils:ExecuteAdb(String) (at Assets/XR/Scripts/XREditorBridge.cs:303)
XRInternal.XRRemoteUtils:SetupADB() (at Assets/XR/Scripts/XREditorBridge.cs:364)
XRInternal.XREditorBridge:CheckADB() (at Assets/XR/Scripts/XREditorBridge.cs:41)
XRController:Update() (at Assets/XR/Scripts/XRController.cs:984)
```

Comment: 8th Wall XRRemote needs to figure out what your adb has set up for port forwarding. That's why it ran adb forward --list. You should try to run adb forward --list in your own command line to see the error message. Perhaps it would then shed lights on what might be wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The connectivity issue with XR Remote on Windows has been identified and fixed in the newest version of 8th Wall XR (8.1.1.216). The fix is currently on the `beta` channel. To change channels, you can do the following from the Unity Editor:

1. Select Assets / XR / 8thWallXR
2. Select the `beta` channel from the resulting inspector pane: [image]